# No such file or directory: '<root>\n

Tags: python

I keep getting the followinge error whenever there is a function call to `xml(productline)`, but if I replace the functioncall with `file = open('config\\' + productLine + '.xml','r')`, it seems to work, why?

```
def xml(productLine):
         with open('config\\' + productLine + '.xml','r') as f:
    return f.read()


def getsanityresults(productline):

xmlfile=xml(productline) // replace with file = open('config\\' + productLine + '.xml','r')
dom = minidom.parse(xmlfile)
data=dom.getElementsByTagName('Sanity_Results')
#print "DATA"
#print data
textnode = data[0].childNodes[0]
testresults=textnode.data
#print testresults
for line in testresults.splitlines():
    #print line
    line = line.strip('\r,\n')
    #print line
    line = re.sub(r'(http://[^\s]+|//[^\s]+|\\\\[^\s]+)', r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', line)
    print line
    #print line       
    resultslis.append(line)
print resultslis
return resultslis
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Dropbox\scripts\announce_build_wcn\wcnbuild_release.py", line 910, in <module>
  main()
 File "C:\Dropbox\scripts\announce_build_wcn\wcnbuild_release.py", line 858, in main
testresults=getsanityresults(pL)
 File "C:\Dropbox\scripts\announce_build_wcn\wcnbuild_release.py", line 733, in   getsanityresults
  dom = minidom.parse(xmlfile)
File "C:\python2.7.3\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1920, in parse
   return expatbuilder.parse(file)
File "C:\python2.7.3\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 922, in parse
fp = open(file, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<root>\n    <PL name = "MSM8930.LA.2.0-PMIC-8917">\n
```

Comment: This code won't run. Please indent it correctly.

Comment: Your function returns a string, not a file object ... I haven't looked at the minidom docs, but that may be important.

Comment: @mgilson - how can I fix it?

Comment: You could wrap the string in a `StringIO` object which behaves like a file in most cases ...

Comment: its not clear to me...can you show a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`minidom.parse()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) expects either filename or file-object as a parameter but you are passing the content of the file, try this:

```
import os
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse(os.path.join('config', productline + '.xml'))
```

Unless you have specific requirements that favors `minidom`; use [`xml.etree.cElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree) to work with xml in Python. It is more pythonic and [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) that you might need in more complex cases supports its API so you don't need to learn twice.

Answer (score 1):

> I replace the functioncall with `file = open('config\\' + productLine + '.xml','r')`, it seems to work, why?

You've got two variables, with subtly different names:

```
xmlfile=xml(productline) // replace with file = open('config\\' + productLine + '.xml','r')
```

There's `productline` (lowercase `l`) and `productLine` (uppercase `L`).

If you use the same variable in both cases, you'll likely see more consistent results.